# Throwing exception after a while

Tags: c#, .net, timer, async-await, put

I'm connecting to a device using a put command over url. However, the setup requires the command being async to be inside a timer. It runs fine for a while then mscorlib.dll starts throwing exceptions and the commands stop being sent.

I have tried to add async in the timer event handler and await before the function that calls the command but it still happens. Not 100% sure how it should be because the timer cannot wait and this happens very fast.

```
button click {
_updateTimer = new Timer(_updateInterval);
_updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerUpdate_Tick);
Start
}

private async void TimerUpdate_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //do other very important stuff that has to be in timer update event
   await myfunction();
}

public static async Task myfunction()
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
       using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), address))
       {
           request.Content = new StringContent("hello");
           var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
           //after some time, it gives an exception on this SendAsync saying connection closed. I did try reconnecting but still gives it again.
        }
    }            
}
```

What I want is to clear some buffer if that is the issue and keep the connection alive and requests being sent as they do for the first 15 seconds.
I'm not sure about the async, awaits and tasks being used correctly.

Thanks

Comment: How many requests are you making? Try creating one instance of `HttpClient` and re-using it instead of creating and disposing it for each request. Or try a library like `RestSharp` that doesn't use `HttpClient`. [Here's an interesting article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: `However, the setup requires the command being async to be inside a timer` - why? There's nothing about the code shown that requires the use of a timer. Plus, the timer will fire every x ms, regardless of whether the previous call is done or not. I wouldn't use a timer. I'd create an asynchronous method that accepts a cancellation token and loops until told to cancel. Inside the loop, fire your HTTP event, then wait the specified `_updateInterval`. Continue until cancellation is requested.

Comment: @ScottHannen please answer my question so that I can choose as answer. Your article is GOLD! It did the trick immediately. Was not aware of that. Very well done and thanks again.

Comment: @PatrickTucci don't you think that if I could have avoided the timer, I wouldn't have written that comment in the first place? Instead of writing a bunch of irrelevant code I stated the facts in a comment. That was not the issue but the timer is a must. Take my word for it.

Comment: https://github.com/olsh/curl-to-csharp/issues/6

Comment: @JustinFarrugia That's absolutely not true. It's not responsible to say the only way to solve this type of problem is with a timer. There are 5 or 6 different ways I can think of off the top of my head to do what you're doing without a `timer`. If you like or prefer timers or your organization forces the use of timers, that's a different story. But that's not what you said. You said this type of problem requires the use of a `timer`. That's absolutely not true.

Comment: I didn't know about the `HttpClient`/`Dispose` issue until a few years ago. Once I became aware of it I started seeing it everywhere. It's scary because in many scenarios someone could run their code and test it for a while without seeing the error, then it shows up in production under load. You're fortunate in that your app apparently makes lots of requests so you're able to find out up front.

Comment: @PatrickTucci it's just a misunderstanding. The time is not there to solve the problem whatsoever. The timer is there because its part of the application. The application doesn't work without the timer; so no timer, no application that gives issue, at all! myfunction needs to be there too because its an integral part of the app too, so I had to make it work. ScottHannen identified the issue immediately without even looking at the timer. I put the timer in my post because you must know that it's in a very fast continuous loop (which in conjunction with the misuse of httpclient caused my issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to execute the requests *for a while* and then they fail, you may have exhausted the number of available sockets. This can happen when we repeatedly create and dispose an `HttpClient` for each request.

Instead we should create the `HttpClient` and reuse it for as long as possible. Technically we should dispose of it when we're done with it because it implements `IDisposable`, but we won't be done with it for as long as we keep reusing it. So the proper way to use and dispose it isn't 100% clear.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) says:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example using HttpClient correctly.

... and follows with this example:

```
public class GoodController : ApiController
{
    // OK
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    static GoodController()
    {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

Another alternative is using something other than `HttpClient`. [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is not only really easy to use but it doesn't use an `HttpClient` so you don't have to worry about disposing it. It handles a lot of things like that internally.

Also, [here's the fun article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) that brought this to my attention.